# split word in Ruby for counting

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

When I split a string "hello world /n" with

```
"hello world \n".scan(/\w+/)
```

I get `["hello", "world"]`

I would like to count \n or \t as string as well .

Comment: Please correct the question. One of your claims is false, and also I can't really understand what it is that you are asking.

Comment: Your first four lines are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
"hello world \n".scan(/\w+|\n/)
```

Comment: This is the one I wanted . Thank you so much .

Answer (score 4):

Do **not** use `\w+` for counting words. It would separate numbers and words with Unicode like so:

```
"The floating point number is 13.5812".scan /\w+/
=> ["The", "floating", "point", "number", "is", "13", "5812"]
```

The same is true for numbers with other delimiters like `"12,000"`.

In **Ruby 1.8** the expression `w+` worked with Unicode, this has changed. If there are Unicode characters in your string, the word will be separated, too.

```
"Die Apfelbäume".scan /\w+/
=> ["Die", "Apfelb", "ume"]
```

There are two options here.

1. You want to **skip numbers** altogether. Fine, just use

   ```
   /\p{Letter}+/
   ```
2. You don't want to skip numbers, because you want to count them as words, too. Then use

   ```
   /\S+/
   ```

   The expression `\S+` will match on non-whitespace characters `/[^ \t\r\n\f]/`. The only disadvantage is, that your words will have other characters attached to them. Like brackets, hyphens, dots, etc. For the sole purpose of counting this should not be a problem.

   If you want to have the words, too. Then you would need to apply additional character stripping.

Answer (score 3):

In strings `\n` has a special meaning: it evolves to caret return which counts as whitespace.
You should escape the backslash: `\\n`.

If you want to split your string by spaces only, you should use

```
"Hello world \n".split(/ /)
```

Comment: It produces the same bad result, see rubydoc:

If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter when splitting str. If pattern is a single space, str is split on whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored. But split(/ /) is good.

Comment: This one seems even simpler than using scan . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
"hello world \n".scan /[\w\n\t]+/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is better if you don't want to split up words with apostrophes (isn't, 90's, etc)

```
"hello world \n".split(/[^\w']+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named character class [:cntrl:].

```
irb(main):001:0> "hello world \n".scan(/\w+|[[:cntrl:]]/)
=> ["hello", "world", "\n"]
```